# Python file still found after deletion

Tags: python

I was trying to make something where if you input a folder name, it will get the resources folder from it, put it in the directory of the file, and delete the old one, but I tried using `shutil.rmtree(  ***(The current resources)***  )` and I thought it would remove everything in the folder, but it deleted the whole folder, which I was fine with because I was going to delete it anyway, But I wait 15 seconds(because I tried fixing this but it didn't work) and I run `shutil.copytree(  ***(the new resources folder)***  ,  (the current directory)  )` but in the output, it says that the folder already exists even after deleting it with shutil.remtree and waiting 15 seconds. Please help.

the code is this

```
shutil.rmtree(ogresource)
print('Importing texture pack')
time.sleep(15)
shutil.copytree(fullpath, directory)
time.sleep(2)
```

"Full path" is the new resources folder, and "directory" is the scripts directory.

Comment: How are "ogresouce" and "directory" related? Is one a subfolder of the other?

Comment: If directory is your current working directory, then it must already exist by definition. Can you show the actual values of ```ogresource```, ```fullpath```, and ```directory```?  I suspect you might just need to change the value of ```directory``` so that it's a new directory within your current working directory. e.g., if ```ogresource = "dir/bobo"```, ```fullpath = "dir/foo"``` and ```directory = "dir`\bar"``, then ```bobo``` and its contents will be deleted, and the new resources will be in a new directory called ```bar```.

Comment: This is the code: https://pastebin.com/EGFUZx71